# How to connect to a server via webdav in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: server, nautilus, 17.10, webdav

I have a bigcommerce site that I need to backup, and to do that I need to connect to it via webdav.  In Ubuntu 16.04 there was an option to connect with nautilus, but after upgrading to 17.10, I don't see the option to do that anymore.  Can I still connect to webdav with nautilus or do I need to install an external program to connect now?  If I can still connect with nautilus, how do I do it? Looking through the Files option, I don't see any way to connect to a server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  You can connect by going to `Other Locations`, then connect to server is at the bottom.